# How to save data from datagrid to SQL Server in C# for the windows application?

Tags: c#

i have a datagrid containing 10 empty rows and columns, i am entering the data into the datagrid through textbox, then i save all the record from the datagrid into the db?

how to save all records from the datagrid.

Anyone Can Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/*YOUR Connection Path*/);
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Service_Sub(Service_No,Service_Date) Values('" + Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')",con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: your code is only for the datagridview not for the datagrid. i want for the datagrid.